# Curve bevel only beveling half a circle

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I beveled a curve grid with the built-in bevel option. The problem is, it's only beveling half of the circle... it's such an annoying little thing, can someone help? Here is a screenshot of an intersection on this curve, only the left half of the circle appears!

[image]

Comment: Did you choose *Full* in Object Data > *Shape* rollout for the curve ?

Comment: It was at "half"... it was right there.... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in b2.81 - Object Data > Shape > Fill Mode - has to be set to "None"

Answer (score 1):

As Mr Zak suggested, the option Object Data > Shape > Fill has to be set to "full" instead of "half", as mine had.